# Why do we see dark black spots in night sky with the naked eye if those same spots are filled with stars when looked at with a telescope?

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life, telescopes, astrophotography

When looking in the sky with the naked eye, we often see dark regions with no stars. However, when we look at those same spots with a telescope, it is full of stars or clouds of dust. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your visual system needs a certain level of light to arrive from a small enough area in your field of view to register.  Your dilated naked eye has a pupil size around 6mm in diameter to receive that light.

The telescope has a large objective lens to increase the capture area.  If you have a 130mm objective, that's over 400 times the area of your pupil. That allows you (depending on the magnification) to register fainter objects.